# Marketing Cloud Cloning to another instance?

Tags: marketing-cloud

What is the easiest way to clone a marketing cloud instance? including journeys, cloud pages, automation rules, data extensions.

I do not see ANY functionality based around this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no “out of the box” functionality readily available. You can use API to fetch assets, such as emails, journeys, etc., store the output locally, and create same assets on the new environment. Even though it is technically feasible - this indeed is quite a time consuming task, just to get an overview of all the development around the SFMC APIs. 
If this is a one-off task, I will advise you to reach out to Salesforce. Their architects have access to internal tools, enabling them to migrate such assets more easily (and hence faster). This is a billable service, but compared to how much work a manual (or evenAPI based) migration might take, this could be a good investment.